# Sass support for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sass, sublimetext

Is there an existing package for editing [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) 2?

This seems to be popular:
https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass

However, after installation, it appears that it only provides syntax highlighting for `scss` files.

Ideally, I'd like syntax highlighting, indentation and completions for the `sass` syntax.

Answer (score 70):

I'd recommend you go with this one: https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle, if only for the amazing code completion - compatible with SASS/SCSS.

Whenever in doubt about packages, and assuming you use the amazing Sublime [**Package Control**](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), just use the [packages list](https://sublime.wbond.net/sort-installs), [type something](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/Sass) (the result will be sorted by the number of installs), and usually the most popular one is the best one.

Comment: so...how do you compile the sass files?  there's no build command, and I tried pulling out the "relevant" files from the n00ge repo, but I apparently don't have "sass" installed?

Comment: Be careful, all Sass plugins for Sublime are helpers to ease out an already working Sass environnement. They won't compile your files and don't remove the need to install Sass itself.

Comment: To answer my comment-question, I ended up wrapping a [standalone SASS compiler](https://github.com/zaus/Sassifier) for Windows in .NET (see github)

Comment: @drzaus - If you are using a Mac, I highly, highly, HIGHLY recommend CodeKit for precompiling your Sass / SCSS files.

Comment: @MattVanAndel, nope, Windows :).  Turns out for just frontend editing, Visual Studio and/or WebMatrix 2 autocompile SASS files (via an extension), but that has nothing to do with Sublime.

Comment: @MaximeFabre Worked like a charm for what I needed, Thanks!

Comment: @drzaus If you or anyone else is still interested, then [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) is pretty much like CodeKit for windows. + it is completely free !

Comment: Just wondering, how do you sort the SublimeText package list by the number of installs?

Answer (score 46):

The reason it is only working for your scss files is because the Ruby HAML highlighting settings overrides your sass highlighting.

Goto `Preferences` > `Browse Packages...`

Find and open `Ruby Haml.tmLanguage` inside the `Rails` folder

change the fileTypes from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>haml</string>
        <string>sass</string> <!-- This line is causing the problem -->
    </array>
    <key>foldingStartMarker</key>
    <string>^\s*([-%#\:\.\w\=].*)\s$</string>
    <key>foldingStopMarker</key>
    <string>^\s*$</string>
...
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>haml</string>
    </array>
    <key>foldingStartMarker</key>
    <string>^\s*([-%#\:\.\w\=].*)\s$</string>
    <key>foldingStopMarker</key>
    <string>^\s*$</string>
...
```

Now the SASS highlighting package you installed should be working properly.

Comment: https://github.com/elia/ruby-haml.tmbundle seems to fix this and has other improvements.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Just open a .sass file and use the menu option "View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as ... > Sass" as described in @bleberi's answer below.

Comment: @Neverender did not know about that one. Thank you, much better solution. Also I believe my answer is quite outdated since it has been fixed in later versions of Sublime.

Answer (score 21):

I did a blog post recently about this: [How to Add SASS Support to Sublime Text](http://aspirecode.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/).

Here's a quick summary:

- To get syntax highlighting, install the [sass-textmate-bundle plugin](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle), called simply `Sass` in Package Control. You'll find that `sass` files won't be properly highlighted by default, but in the post I detail a two-second fix that doesn't involve hacking up any of Sublime's default plugins.
- Install the [SASS Build plugin](https://github.com/jaumefontal/SASS-Build-SublimeText2) to enable building `sass` and `scss` files from Sublime.
- Add the [SublimeOnSaveBuild plugin](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild), which automatically runs a build whenever you save changes to a file.

Check out the [blog post](http://aspirecode.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/) for full details.

Comment: This post is brilliant. Had me set up in no time.

Answer (score 18):

regarding to [this article](http://aspirecode.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/) :

1. install sass-textmate-bundle plugin
2. open some sass file
3. click **View** | **Syntax** | **Open all with current extension as …** | **Sass**

Comment: Very helpful. To add on to this, the name of the plugin is just plainly "SCSS" but in the description it writes the TextMake SCSS Official Bundle. My short key for installing plugin for Mac is Command+Shift+P and search "install" for Package Control: Install Package.

Answer (score 3):

If a package conflict is causing trouble ( like the Haml issue ) and you need to edit / override a package like removing the `<string>sass</string>` part from the `Ruby HAML` file, then I would **highly recommend** the [Package Resource Viewer (and editor)](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) plugin.

1. Install `PackageResourceViewer`
2. Use the palette to do `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`: 
   [image]
3. Select `Rails` then `Ruby Haml.tmLanguage`: 
   [image: screen-2014-02-25_10.37.09.png]
4. Comment out the offending line: 
    [image: screen-2014-02-25_10.39.12.png]
5. Save the file ( this is the awesome part, because the `PackageResourceViewer` automatically saves just the overridden part automatically to the correct place.
6. Done.

Now go and tweak all the little settings / defaults in the other packages that have been annoying you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the problem of https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass not recognizing Rails default `.css.sass` files because of the extra `.css` extension. I agree with Maxime above that using https://github.com/seaofclouds/sass-textmate-bundle is a better option and that installing via the package control is ideal http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control.  The way to fix the .css.sass extension not being recognized is to edit the Sass package directly. Go to `Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Browse Packages` and edit the `Sass\Syntaxes\Sass.tmLanguage` file. Add `<string>css.sass</string>` to the `<array>` block.

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
  <string>sass</string>
  <string>css.sass</string>
  <string>scss</string>
</array>
```