# Sublime text 2 SASS completions

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2

I used [sublime-text-haml-sass](https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass) to get [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) support for sublime text 2. It all works except css completions.

There are files "css_completions.py" and "css_completions.pyc" in folder C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\css which are responsible for providing completions. I tiried putting those files in SASS folder in packages, but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to copy completions from css package to SASS ?

Comment: Check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309185/sass-support-for-sublime-text-2

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, but completion doesn't work there either.

Comment: This was driving me crazy too! I installed the SASS package using the package control manager, but then lost my color styling for SASS after relaunch, but after just switching the Code colors from SASS to CSS my code completions are back now! And great link @David

Answer (score 1):

Use [nathos / sass-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle) to get completions.  You can install with the package manager by searching for "sass".