# Sass support for sublime text 3

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

Is there a way to make autocomplete work for scss in the same way it works for css?
For example I type `backg` and then `tab` and it gives me `background:;` but not in scss files...

I have installed all packages to support scss... but there is only syntax highlighting that is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Emmet (formerly Zen Coding), it is an extremely powerful tool to do css (and scss), example :
I type `bi` and press `tab` and it gives me : `background-image: url(|);` (with the `|` your cursor).

If you are interested, please take a look at this:

- [Emmet for sublime](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/), and [all the abbreviation](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) (Emmet is very good with HTML too -- look what is happening when you type, for example, `nav>ul>li`...)

*Now, how to make it works with scss*:

The answer is [here](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/issues/38)

- You have to install the package [sass-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle) for scss and do what I have wrote.
- If you need sass and not scss, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309185/sass-support-for-sublime-text-2), especially the second response from Alexander Ekdahl