# Sublime Text 3 - SASS (scss) autocomplete variables from another files

Tags: autocomplete, sass, sublimetext3

I have two files:

variables.scss:

```
$my_var: #fff;
```

module.scss:

```
@import 'variables';

.body { background: $my_var;}
```

And Visual Studio provides me nice hints - when I'm typing `$my` in module.scss I see all variables from imported files that matches to `$my`. 
Simple.

But Sublime Text 3 autocompletes only variables from module.scss, not from other imported files. I have installed All Autocomplete package, it doesn't work... Any ideas? It is important feature for me...

Comment: I've just tested Atom, and I see that Atom can do that, so maybe I should use Atom instead of Sublime. Anyway, I'm still lookinig for answer !:)

Answer (score 1):

Question was answered here: [Sass support for sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618579/sass-support-for-sublime-text-3)

From that link: 
You can install Emmet (formerly Zen Coding), it is an extremely powerful tool to do css (and scss), example :
I type `bi` and press `tab` and it gives me : `background-image: url(|);` (with the `|` your cursor).

If you are interested, please take a look at this:

- [Emmet for sublime](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/), and [all the abbreviation](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) (Emmet is very good with HTML too -- look what is happening when you type, for example, `nav>ul>li`...)

*Now, how to make it works with scss*:

The answer is [here](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/issues/38)

- You have to install the package [sass-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle) for scss and do what I have wrote.
- If you need sass and not scss, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309185/sass-support-for-sublime-text-2), especially the second response from Alexander Ekdahl

Comment: I've bought Webstorm and it was great decision,but thanks for answer!

Comment: This does not actually answer the authors question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is what fixed the problem for me:

1. Have an active tab with SASS (SCSS) file and then go to `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User`
2. Paste this `` "word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?" ``
3. Save and profit.

Hope it helps. There is this [github issue](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete/issues/18) if you want to have more information.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the [AllAutocomplete plugin](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete)

The biggest drawback to using this plugin is that the file that it reads the variables from has to be open.  Unfortunately I haven't found any better way to achieve this.

### Sublime text 3 support?

This plugin didn't work for me out of the box with ST3. I had to make a small modification to the user settings file to get it to work.

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

Adding this to your user sublime settings file should do the trick.  Here is the github issue where this originated from.

https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete/issues/18