# Autocomplete with SASS missing semicolon on Sublime Text?

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext2, emmet

I've just started using SASS with Sublime Text 2 and really enjoying it. However, some of the autocomplete features that worked with CSS, do not work with SASS. 
For example, on a CSS file when I type: `float` and press `tab`, it automatically adds a semicolon

`float:`

And the same if I then add `left` and press tab, I get

`float:left;`

However, it does not do this in a SCSS file. Is there a way to get this autocomplete back, but with SASS?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309185/sass-support-for-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/70

> For SASS syntax, default dialect is sass, not scss (it’s important).
>   According to examples from http://sass-lang.com, closing semicolon is
>   not required.
>
> But you can alter this behaviour: in User’s Emmet.sublime-settings
>   file, add the sass.propertyEnd property for preferences section, like
>   this:

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "sass.propertyEnd": ";"
    }
}
```

Comment: When I type db and tab, I get display: block (without the semicolon at the end). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @GregoryBolkenstijn I've updated the answer but my edit is pending review. Just add `"disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete": false
` to your Preferences.sublime-settings file