# Sass autocomplete in Sublime text 3

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use Sublime text 3 and installed plugins [Sass](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sass), [Syntax Highlighting for Sass](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Syntax%20Highlighting%20for%20Sass), [CSS Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Completions) and [CSS Extended Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions), but when I work with .scss, there aren't any auto-complete options for CSS keywords.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309185/sass-support-for-sublime-text-2) post, where isn't mentioned auto-complete functionality and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953759/autocomplete-with-sass-on-sublime-text) post, where is mentioned only emmet.

Anybody knows how to add sass auto-complete to sublime text 3?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem that you are likely running into is that Sublime is loading your .scss file with Sass syntax. The Sass syntax is a bit different than SCSS (they did away with the curly braces and semi-colons. If you go to [this link](http://sass-lang.com/guide) you can see the difference between the two). To get your .scss files working you will need the [SCSS plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SCSS). Install it and set the syntax to SCSS and the auto-complete should start working for you.

Comment: it's such a shame that the `SCSS` plug-in doesn't recognise the [ampersand operator](https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle/issues/192)...

Comment: I had to Remove Package SASS and SCSS. Then I reinstalled SCSS (first) and then SASS. Works fine now. Be sure to set your Syntax to be SCSS. ("open all with -> SCSS")